# If a prostitute "solicits" a potential client, what verb is used for requesting or engaging a prostitute's services?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

If the prostitute solicits, what do the customers do?

Do you *rent* a prostitute?

Comment: Quick googling brings up simple phrases like "visiting a prostitute" or "going to a prostitute".

Comment: Clearly, if you bring one home, it's neither visiting or going to.

Comment: Please consider expanding this question with an example sentence or some additional background.

Comment: Great Italian movie: Brutti, Sporchi i Cattivi (Ugly, Dirty and Bad). He brings her home and the movie is an absolute riot.

Comment: 'swiped right'?

Comment: ..... purchase!

Answer (score 6):

Generally the word "solicit" can be used in both ways. A prostitute solicits clients, and the "johns" (those patronising a prostitute's services) also solicit the prostitutes. (note, this may vary by jurisdiction, as noted later). If you've ever watched the show Cops you might have come across the police officer charging the "john" with "soliciting prostitution." But in case the high bar set by reality TV won't convince you, let's take Wikipedia:

> A streetwalker **solicits** customers on the streets or in public places,
>   while a call girl makes appointments by phone, or in recent years,
>   through email or the internet.
>
> Clients of prostitutes, most often men by prevalence, are sometimes
>   known as johns or tricks in North America and punters in the British
>   Isles. These slang terms are used among both prostitutes and law
>   enforcement for persons who **solicit** prostitutes.
>   [Prostitution article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution) (bolding is mine)

And in case you believe Wikipedia is a left-wing plot, let's take a dictionary definition to support my point:

> solicit
>   3. To commit the criminal offense of enticing or inciting (another) to commit an illegal act.
>   4. To approach or accost (a person) with an offer of sex in exchange for payment.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/solicit)

The prostitutes might be committing definition 4, whereas the johns might be committing definition 3.

And in case The Free Dictionary is wrong....

> Solicitation of Prostitution
>  Depending on the state, solicitation of
>   prostitution can mean either when a prostitute advertises his or her
>   availability to perform sexual acts for compensation, or when a
>   potential patron offers to pay for sex.
>   [criminaldefenselawyer.com](https://www.criminaldefenselawyer.com/crime-penalties/federal/Solicitation-of-Prostitution.htm)

To the extent that the john is a patron of the prostitute, the john is patronising the prostitute's services.

If you type "rent a prostitute" in an internet search both "rent" and "hire" commonly arise. I'll refrain from linking you, but feel free to look for yourself.

Comment: Hire the services of a prostitute? Cheers. :)